# Copy value of an alt and create a data element with this value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I copy the value of a 'alt' and turn into a 'data-id' for several sample images (with jQuery):

```
<img src="" alt='test1' />
<img src="" alt='test2' />
<img src="" alt='test3' />
```

As should be:

```
<img src="" alt='test1' data-id='test1' />
<img src="" alt='test2' data-id='test2' />
<img src="" alt='test3' data-id='test3' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all the images with `.each()` and add an attribute `data-id`.

```js
$('img').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('data-id', $(this).attr('alt'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" alt='test1' />
<img src="" alt='test2' />
<img src="" alt='test3' />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly this. :)